# Vectorising numpy.einsum

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vectorization, numpy-einsum

I have following four tensors

1. H (h, r)
2. A (a, r)
3. D (d, r)
4. T (a, t, r)

For each `i` in `a`, there is a corresponding `T[i]` of the shape `(t, r)`.

I need to do a `np.einsum` to produce the following result (`pred`):

```
pred = np.einsum('hr, ar, dr, tr ->hadt', H, A, D, T[0])
for i in range(a):
    pred[:, i:i+1, :, :] = np.einsum('hr, ar, dr, tr ->HADT', H, A[i:i+1], D, T[i])
```

However, I want to do this computation without using a for loop. The reason is that I' m using `autograd` which doesn't currently work with item assignments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be using all the dimensions for `T` -

```
np.einsum('Hr, Ar, Dr, ATr ->HADT', H, A, D, T)
```

Since, we need to sum-reduce axis-`r` across all inputs, while keeping all others (axes) in the output, I don't see any intermediate way of doing it/bringing in any dot-based tools on this to leverage BLAS.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow (wrongly) thought that it might be a bad practice to have the same characters repeated in the einsum string. Like, we have two As on the LHS of `->`. I think this restriction applies to the RHS of `->`?

Comment: @NipunBatra Repetition on LHS for different variables means keep them aligned. Repetition for one variable is not allowed or LHS or RHS for obvious reasons.

Comment: 'ii' is the trace, 'ii->i' is the diagonal. 'i,i' and 'i,i->i' are also ok.  Repeating the '->ii' in the output is wrong.

Comment: @hpaulj Ah yes for the special case of same length axes. Thanks for the reminder!